# Curved space or curved spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, terminology, space, curvature

As I understand it, you can have *time + flat space = curved spacetime.*

1. So, when one is trying to emphasise that there is a curvature to the space, is it more technically correct to say *curved space* in favour of *curved spacetime.*
2. Does anyone do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for starters, *time + flat space*, as you put it, isn't necessarily curved. The obvious example being Minkowski space, of course.

It *can* be curved though, depending on how you join the two to form a spacetime. For example, flat space can be joined with a time coordinate to form a hyperbolic
space with metric
$$ds^2 = \frac{-dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 +dz^2}{t^2},$$ such that for every $t$ fixed, we get a flat spacial slice, but the total space is most definitely curved.

I can't speak for the entire physics community out there, but I am under the impression that "curved spacetime" would be the commonly used expression.

Edit: Oh dear, I think I finally understood your question correctly. I suppose "curved space" would be an adequate description, though I can think of very few situation where you would want to explicitly emphasize the spacial curvature. Mind you that this is a very coordinate-dependent statement, to boot: if your curved spacetime is of the form "time + flat space" in one set of coordinates, in another set of coordinates, the spatial part may very well be curved, and the other way around.

Comment: The only example I can think of is if you're studying the embeddings of curved spaces in flat higher-dimensional spacetimes.

Comment: Definitely worth emphasizing: time + flat space = spacetime, which can very well be flat. Just because GR can handle curvature doesn't mean everything in GR is curved.

Answer (score 0):

They're both technically correct, it depends on what you are talking about.  It is possible to have the space be curved, the spacetime be curved, or to have neither be curved.